# How do I bring NLopt to work for Python3 on macOS Catalina with homebrew?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, homebrew, pyenv, nlopt

below you first find a summary and skip hint to the main problem and then the long version with everything. This is my first question here and I hope I didn't break any rules with making the post so long and having multiple questions... 
**I'm happy about any answer regarding any of the questions!!**

*Edit: I shortened the whole post and cut out all "questions on the way" so it's only about the nlopt difficulties now*

## Short

Installing nlopt via homebrew is not working because files are missing. For infos on this part ONLY skip to the bold "Main Problem(s)".

**Warning:** I'm pretty new to all this stuff with the shell, homebrew, etc. so I'm not really familiar with names and terms. Please be patient with me :)

---

## Long

Reinstalling my "old" MacBook from the scratch I had to install everything again and read a lot about how things work. All the way reading countless posts and guides I learned as much as I thought I needed - and as few as possible due to the amount. Now I am stuck. 
For the project I work on I need Python 3, CobraPy and NLopt. That's what I did so far (I'm listing all my commands and some resulting warnings bc I don't know what might become relevant):

*I'm using the zsh shell and that's all happening at ~ if not stated otherwise. Furthermore I always installed all things being called necessary by the documentation or as precaution if stated so by guides (to which I don't have links anymore bc I'm working on all of this including  more since a week))*

1. Install XCode

   - via AppStore
   - `xcode-select --install`
2. Install homebrew

   ```bash
   % ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   % brewup # alias brewup='brew update; brew upgrade; brew cleanup; brew doctor'
   ```
3. Pyenv

   ```bash
   % brew install pyenv
   ==> Installing dependencies for pyenv: autoconf, openssl@1.1, pkg-config and readline
   % echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
   % source ~/.zshrc
   ```
4. preparing the Python installation

   ```bash
   % brew install zlib sqlite sqlite3 xz openssl readline
   % brewup
   # and bc someone said it's necessary for no problems with build:
   % export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib"
   % export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include"
   ```
5. Python

   ```bash
   % brew upgrade pyenv
   % pyenv install 3.8.1
   % pyenv global 3.8.1
   % pip install --upgrade pip
   ```

   and verified it worked with `version`, `versions`, `which python`, `python -V`, `pip -V`
6. Pyenv-virtualenv & Extras

   ```bash
   % brewup 
   % brew install pyenv-virtualenv
   % echo -e 'if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
   ```

   and testing by creating a VE, set it locally as standard in the project folder with `pyenv local VE` and

   ```bash
   (VE) folder/project % pip install numpy
   (VE) folder/project % sudo pip install cobra
   ~ % brew install grep findutils # bc "good for cobra"
   ```
7. NLopt

   ```bash
   % brew install cmake
   % brew install nlopt
   ```

   No real problems so far. Everything seems fine. 
    
   And then I start trying to finish the NLopt Installation with the instructions from the documentation/README.md:

---

## Main Problem(s)

continuing for nlopt after `% brew install nlopt`

```bash
~ % cd /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.6.1
Cellar/nlopt/2.6.1 % mkdir build
Cellar/nlopt/2.6.1 % cd build
nlopt/2.6.1/build % cmake ..
CMake Error: The source directory "/usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.6.1" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

After some more blind tries even in nlopt/2.6.1/lib/cmake/nlopt I found that in the homebrew installation of NLopt a lot of stuff is missing compared to the git files (see [GitHub NLopt](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt)) - including folders and the needed CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
Cellar/nlopt/2.6.1 % ls -1
AUTHORS
COPYING
COPYRIGHT
ChangeLog
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
NEWS.md
README.md
TODO
include
lib
share
```

**Question A: Did I do something wrong?** I searched for people having similar problems but were not able to find help.

**Question B: can I just manually download NLopt, put all the files in the directory above** (replacing the things there (except for the .brew file)), **just ignore that homebrew was goofing and then do the final calibration with cmake?**

Regardless how we bring this to work: I read something about that if you don't use the system python then you have to link certain things anew after doing the cmake and make thing with nlopt. 
**Question C: when I put the new links in cmake, do I have to link the Python version I want to work with (here 3.8.1) or do I have to link the shim from pyenv?** And in the first case would I have to relink every time I upgrade to a new version (what's why I hope the second one is correct)?

---

Recherching again I also found this side [PyPI nlopt](https://pypi.org/project/nlopt/) that "supports Python versions 3.6" and "setups a tool chain to build pypi wheels for the NLOpt library". This NLopt is installed via `pip`. Now: 
 
**Question D: Does this mean this also works if I pip install it in my VE?
And does it still need to be activated via cmake etc?** 
BC it's referring to the documentation on using NLopt with Python but not stating anything about the setup after pip-installing.

---

I don't know what to do at this point: what would be just filling and crowding my system and what will let me start working on my project? Thanks in advance :)